# Creating a 2x2 grid of images in a single array based on 4 images in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, subplot

I've been stuck on this question and I have figured it out in the image below. The second image is the first task that task 2 is based on. I have been told that the solution needs to be in a single new array. The following starter script was given: `grid_image =`  and `plt.imshow(grid_image)`.

[image: Question to solve: Task 1]

[image: Taks 1]

Task 1 code:

```
images = np.load('albatrosses.npy')
images = images.reshape((-1,56,56,3))
plt.imshow(images[0])
```

Task 2 code: He says he wants it on a single array.

```
grid_image = images
fig, axis = plt.subplots(2,2)
axis[0,0].imshow(images[0])
axis[0,1].imshow(images[1])
axis[1,0].imshow(images[2])
axis[1,1].imshow(images[3])
```

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: Task 1 code:                                                                                                            images = np.load('albatrosses.npy')
images = images.reshape((-1,56,56,3))
plt.imshow(images[0])

Comment: Task two code that I have but he has said it's wrong. He wants it on a single array: grid_image = images

fig, axis = plt.subplots(2,2)
axis[0,0].imshow(images[0])
axis[0,1].imshow(images[1])
axis[1,0].imshow(images[2])
axis[1,1].imshow(images[3])

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using de CIFAR10 dataset from TensorFlow. For this task, you can use [NumPy Indexing on 'ndarrays'](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#).

```
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
(images, _), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

grid_image = images
fig, axis = plt.subplots(2,2)
axis[0,0].imshow(images[0])
axis[0,1].imshow(images[1])
axis[1,0].imshow(images[2])
axis[1,1].imshow(images[3])
```

[image]

```
print(images[0].shape) #shape(h,w,c)
print(images[0].dtype)
plt.imshow(images[0])
```

[image]

And here goes the code you need: First, we calculate the shape of the new grid image with the sub-images, considering their height and width. Then we create a new array, filled with zeros and the same data type, with the resulting shape (including the 3-channel dimension).

```
output_shape = (images[0].shape[0]+images[2].shape[0], images[0].shape[1]+images[1].shape[1], 3)
grid_image = np.zeros(output_shape, dtype='uint8')

#add sub image 0
grid_image[ :images[0].shape[0], :images[0].shape[1], :] = images[0]
#add sub image 1
grid_image[ :images[1].shape[0], images[1].shape[1]:, :] = images[1]
#add sub image 2
grid_image[ images[2].shape[0]:, :images[2].shape[1], :] = images[2]
#add sub image 3
grid_image[ images[3].shape[0]:, images[3].shape[1]:, :] = images[3]

print(grid_image.shape)
print(grid_image.dtype)
plt.imshow(grid_image)
```

[image]

I hope this may help you.